Install Oracle Middleware 12c and 11c on the same machine
I need to install Oracle Forms&Reports Builder on a pc (windows 10 pro 64G) where Oracle Middleware 12c is already installed.
I was able to install Oracle 12c in a pc having 11c installed, but i cant manage the inverse scenario. running wls1036_generic.jar causes several errors.
Is there a way to install 11g without having to uninstall Oracle 12?
thanks
